# Does Monaco editor support xml schema validation?

Tags: monaco-editor

Monaco supports json schema validation. But does it also support xml schema validation? 
If there is no automatic support, how can I hook into the events to provide schema validation functionality?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: At the time of asking, we didnt have the support.